# Catch event on nth div click

Tags: jquery

What's the possible way to catch event on click, if event target must be some nth div?
For example, we've following html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How can I fire up event only if have clicked on second div?

Something like that:

```
if($(event.target).is('item:eq(1)')){alert('second')}
```

or

```
if($(event.target).is('.item:eq(1)')){alert('second')}
```

is not working. JSFiddle for quick edit: http://jsfiddle.net/UXqM2/

**Thanks everyone for answers.** But I don't need code to be strictly binded on one element, that's why I was asking about event target. I've function which starting like

```
clicktarget.on('click', function(event){ //some code here });
```

Where clicktarget is just an `item` class from example above. And I don't want to write 3 functions which will work similar just to change one line of code - it's not good, so I asked about this because I want to catch event ***inside*** function and just change one line of code.
So I guess index() should do the trick.

Comment: So for example you want every second div to have an on click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class is doesn't matter. jquery takes current element on click defaultly using `$(this)` - denotes the current element

```
$('.item').on('click', function(event){ 
       alert($(this).index() + 1)     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the nth-child css selector:

```
$('.item:nth-child(2)').on('click', function(event){
   alert('test'); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UXqM2/6/)

Comment: +1 for nth-child selector. This is probably the most efficient way to accomplish this and the most customization.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.item:eq(1)').click(function () { alert('second'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

No if statement needed, only:

```
$('.item:eq(1)').click(function(){
    alert('second');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXqM2/2/)

```
$('.item').on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.item:eq(1)')) {
        alert('second');
    }
});
```

you were missing the `.` before `item` (you want the items with `item` class), also you were missing the `);` at the end of your code to complete the `on()`.

Also, if this is the only logic you are concerned with, you could just put the listener directly on that element only...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXqM2/9/)

```
$('.item:eq(1)').on('click' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
if($(event.target).is('.item') && $(event.target).index() === 1){
   alert('second')
}
```

---

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UXqM2/8/)

---

### Sidenote:

You have a wrong closing of your bound event that should be `});`.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UXqM2/10/)**
 It is too late ..any way try this

```
$('.item').on('click', function(event){ 
    ($(this).index()==1)?alert("two"):alert("not two")
});
```